# 「Accepted Answer (花まるアンサー)」の記号

Tags: 討議, デザイン

現在「花まるアンサー」の記号は：

[image: 花まるアンサーマーク]

日本では「チェック記号」は英語と真反対の意味を持っています。スタックオーバーフローの英語版を利用したことがあれば問題ないですが、サイトを利用したことがないユーザーは理解できると思いますか？

Comment: 補足: 「花まるアンサー」は[私が出した訳語案です](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/11/stack-overflow%E3%81%AE%E5%B0%82%E9%96%80%E7%94%A8%E8%AA%9E#comment171_265)。

Answer (score 1):

チェック記号は日本では「少しポジティブな印付け」という程度で、ネガティブな意味合いはないと思います。(ネガティブなのは "×") なので、まったく意味不明、という状態にはならないと思います。

ただ、「花まるアンサー」を採用するならば、チェック記号も花まるっぽい見た目にした方が、メンタルモデルが一致してよいと思います。

Comment: 小学校で教えた時、チェック記号は「×」と同じ意味合いがありました。正しいは「⚪︎」で、誤りは「チェック」が多かった。ちょっと調べます。

Comment: テストの採点でチェック記号を「×」と同じ意味で使う先生は多いです。
googleの画像検索で"テスト 採点"をキーワードにして検索していただくと分かりやすいです。
しかしチェック記号が緑色のため、多くの人が「○」として使っているのだと連想できるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: @jmac そういえば私もチェック付きの回答用紙をもらったことがあるような気がします。その時は「間違っている」というより「ここは再チェックが必要」という意味で受けとめたように思います。

Comment: @BladeanMericle (通知用にコメントを分けます) いずれにせよ、SEのような「チェック記号しか選択肢がない」場面では「丸とチェックの対比としてのチェック記号」の意味合いは薄れると思います。

Answer (score 1):

チェック記号については、コンピュータに触れている物であれば、それがチェックボックスで使われている物と同じことがわかりますから、ネガティブな意味合いととられることはないでしょう。日本の学校でテストの採点時に誤答に対して使われるということはありますが、絶対的なルールではありません。聞いた話では、大学になるとチェックの意味合いを逆にする先生がでてきて、「あの先生逆だから混乱する」という会話は  freshman までのようです。

日本のユーザに対しては、それがチェックである、ということよりも、それが緑色であるということのほうが、ポジティブな意味合いを伝えています。赤字になると逆の意味に取る人が多くなるでしょう。私が問題と思ったのは、それがなんとなく良い意味だとわかっても、本当の意味は何なのかがわからないことです。最低、マウスオーバーをしたときに出るヘルプを現在の "`The question owner accepted this as the best answer`" から変えてほしいです。できれば、クリック可能にして FAQ に飛ばすようにするとなお良いのではないでしょうか。

訳文としては以下を提案します。

「`質問者がこの回答をベストアンサーとして受け入れました`」